# mvc3 how to transfer list objects between action methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, list, action, selectlistitem

I have a List object in 1 controller and I was wondering how can I transfer it to the next controller for example this is what I have

```
public ActionResult namelist()
    {
        var mynames = new List<everyname>
       {
           new everyname{ firstname ="john", Lastname= "henny"},                     
              new everyname{ firstname = "bob", Lastname = "cosso"},  
      new everyname{ firstname = "bill", Lastname = "luther"},
      new everyname{ firstname ="mike", Lastname= "jones"}

       };
        return View(mynames);
    }

 // how can i transfer the above list with information into this action below

         public ActionResult newlist()
    {
       // i tried transfering the list here and it did not work
        var namelist = new namelist()
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =  namelist.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = namelist,
            Text = namelist

        });
```

how can i transfer things? i am lost on this.

Comment: How are you calling the `newlist` action? The HTTP protocol is stateless, so if you want to send some values to this controller action you should include them in your HTTP request. The default model binder will take care of the rest, assuming you have respected the naming convention. IMHO understanding the HTTP protocol is an absolute must prerequisite before getting into ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

In the NameList method you can add this line:

```
TempData["namelist"] = mynames;
```

then at the top of the newList method add this line:

```
var namelist = Tempdata["namelist"] as List<everyname>;
```

Once you access a value in TempData it is purged from the TempData object